# Animated scroll of UITableview like credits at the end of a movie

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, animation, scroll, uiscrollview

I have to make a screen for the credits of my app that behaves like the credits at the end of a movie. I was using a uitextview but we need sticky headers like a tableview. So I switched to that but am unsure how to automate/animate slowly scrolling the uitableview to the bottom. Once there I would reload the data and run it again unless you close the view controller.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that a UITableView makes the most sense and you need to content to by dynamic (if it's static you could just use a PDF and a UIImageView) you need to get the surrounding `UIScrollView` and call it's `scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:)` method to animate the view.